# Physical location of abstract objects

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, plato

I was reading about the idea of a specific colour as an abstract object as defined by Plato, and how in 'Parmenides' he struggled with the fact that the type cannot be single and exist in multiple places without being 'split apart'. I am interested in why some believe that such abstract objects need a physical location when their instances only need to, why did Plato and further on Russell discuss the idea of the location of abstracts as if they had physical sense?

Comment: This is pretty vague. Can you give some quotes?

Comment: If they exist at all, they exist in the mind: human, collective, of God...

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time somebody made the "use-mention error" then could I be smothered by the large number in my bank account?

Comment: @DavidGudeman I am referring to the exploration of forms in Plato's 'Parmenides'  which explores the idea that forms must be 'split apart'

Comment: i think this is a repeat question

Comment: Not having read the Parmenides, Plato seems to advocate for the Forms being "physically" real in a realm different from ours - where our soul gets to see them directly in between different lives in this realm. If you take that standpoint it becomes clear that it's hard to explain how two things can partake in the same Form without being 'split apart'.

Comment: Yes, I recognized where the question was coming from, but I don't think your characterization is accurate. That's why I wanted some specific quote.

Comment: Well, ideas certainly can exist in space. Ever hear of the mindscape? Or how ideas can be connected? So talking about the "where" of abstract ideas is not so stupid.

Comment: See [Abstract objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abstract-objects/#HistRema): "The contemporary distinction between abstract and concrete is not an ancient one. Indeed, there is a strong case for the view that, despite occasional exceptions, it played no significant role in philosophy before the 20th century. The modern distinction bears some resemblance to Plato’s distinction between Forms and Sensibles. But Plato’s Forms were supposed to be causes par excellence, whereas abstract objects are generally supposed to be causally inert." 1/2

Comment: "The abstract/concrete distinction [...] becomes a central focus for philosophical discussion primarily in the 20th century. The origins of this development are obscure, but one crucial factor appears to have been the breakdown of the allegedly exhaustive distinction between mental and material objects, which had formed the main division for ontologically-minded philosophers since Descartes. One signal event in this development is Frege’s insistence that the objectivity and aprioricity of the truths of mathematics entail that numbers are neither material beings nor ideas in the mind." 2/2

Comment: Regarding Plato, see [Forms](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-metaphysics/#8): "The rigid separation of Forms from sensible particulars, Plato's idea that there are ‘Two Worlds’, is embodied in Plato's isolation of the two ways of being, Being and Partaking. The criteria and the properties which differentiate Forms and particulars are related to their respective ways of being." Thus *Forms* exist? Yes, of course: they are "causes" of partuculars.

Comment: @DavidGudeman you are correct, where I was wrong was seeing our 'abstracts' as being equivalent to the platonic forms which plato saw as being equally physical as its particulars.

Comment: And see Mark Balaguer, [Abstract Objects](https://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/view/document/obo-9780195396577/obo-9780195396577-0384.xml): "An abstract object is a non-physical, non-mental object that exists outside of space and time and is wholly unextended. For example, one might think that numbers are abstract objects."

Comment: Conclusion: abstract objects are real but they are not "physically located".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I would argue that some abstract objects are located in space--namely the abstract points, lines, planes, and spaces that we appeal to when we are surveying property or putting up a building or doing other things with space. The force produced by a rocket is an abstract object with a location at the rear of the rocket.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA -- you have extensive enough commentary that you should turn these comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract objects have puzzled philosophers for millennia, and there is not a current consensus on how to deal with them.

One "troubling" aspect of abstractions is that they appear not to be material, or physical. They constitute no mass nor energy, and may not even have any actual instances in history.  This is "troubling" for the simpler forms of materialism and physicalism, as then abstractions would not exist -- yet they certainly seem to.  Most philosophers who are physicalists today have adapted physicalism to accept that not everything in the universe IS physical -- IE physicalism is not a monism.  At least this is the case according to Daniel Stoljar in his relatively recent book "Physicalism".  This relaxation of physicalism to no longer be a monism is also apparent in Kim (Physicalism or Something Near Enough), Papineau (The Rise of Physicalism), and Melnyk (A Physicalist Manifesto).  None of these authors focus on abstract objects, so they don't provide answers to your questions -- but they illustrate how the dominant ontology in philosophy today is still struggling with this issue, and does not have a straightforward answer to it.

The two dominate approaches to abstractions are abstract realism, and nominalism.  A lot of physicalists used to lean toward nominalism, as that appears to give a path to maintain physicalism as a monism.    But that is not really clearly the case.  And that is particularly true now that most physicalists have fully adopted emergence as a valid phenomenon in our world.  Where are "nominal" operations taking place, other than in a logic space?  Even if "we" create temporary logic space to do a useful nominal exercise -- isn't' that just another word for an only temporary emergence of an abstract space and objects?  And what is the "we" who is doing this "nominally"?  Emergent physicalists today have generally accepted the reality of consciousness and selfhood, and hold them to be emergent non-physical phenomenon, just with a physical DEPENDENCE to them.  Neither selfhood nor abstractions need to be only "nominal" if physicalists abandon monism for "dependence", and this tactic has drastically reduced the need for physicalists to adopt nominalism.  Nominalism can therefore be seen as a rationalization tool that physicalism resorted to when it tried to maintain itself as a monism, but has now lost most of its popularity.

The clearest ontological description of abstract realism I have found is in Popper's adaption of Three Worlds from Frege.  https://tannerlectures.utah.edu/_resources/documents/a-to-z/p/popper80.pdf Most philosophers today have accepted that abstract objects are real, and exist.  This is the case for math realism, and for moral realism.  The general claim that all abstractions exist -- is less clear.  Most physicalists today have implicitly accepted a world 1 plus world 3 dualism as the basic nature of their universe, with consciousness as an emergent phenomenon from world 1.  This is a very similar ontology to Popper's but emergent non-monal physicalism is more suspicious of the independent reality of consciousness than Popper is.  Popper's three world emergent triplism itself also grants less independence to consciousness than does Cartesian spiritual dualism.  But the differences between these views all focus on tweaks to how they address consciousness, NOT abstract objects.  Most philosophy today is fully compatible with abstract object realism, despite the discomfort or queasiness that many philosophers feel about adopting a fully populated world 3 ontology.